Ethernet speed change 100M to 1000M
My goal is to set the speed from 100Mb/s to 1Gb. The device is Lenovo ThinkCentre M700 and the OS is Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS. As I found on the web this command must do the work. My router is Asus RT-AC68U and CAT5e is used to connect devices.
sudo ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on

The only thing that happens is that the server disconnects from the network until I reboot it. I assumed the problem is that the server cannot connect to the network because DHCP is not working, and I set it manually through the Netplan YAML file, but I have not had any luck.

You should never have to force speed. Check that your cables are OK, and try with a different cable. If you have to force speed you have to force it at both ends. 999 of 1000 times the problem is cabling when autonegotiation doesn't work.

Indeed for some reason the cable was the problem. But its cat5e I tested the cable with cable tester and all 8 lights are lightning however tomorrow I will change the connectors because I think they might be the problem.

A simple tester with light diodes doesn't test that the cable is according to Cat5E specification. It merely tests that there's connectivity. In general, never terminate cable in RJ45 plugs yourself; terminate in sockets and use pre-made patchcables.

If you want to test actual cable specification, you need a qualifier such as Fluke CableIQ. These typically costs >1kUSD, and only make sense for professional network installers. Cheaper testers are next to worthless, and a better test is to use two computers with iperf3.
